# Google Drive API v3 .NET - Why someone can consume my quota, incur charges with the client secret?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, google-drive-api, authorization

I am still a newbie in google drive api and oauth2 authorization. I am working on asp.net web form application with google drive api v3. Found no problem so far with all creating folders, uploading, getting list, deleting on the drive going well. I just want to know why client secret needs to be private or secret.

Here is the message on https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started. They say:
"Warning: Keep your client secret private. If someone obtains your client secret, they could use it to consume your quota, incur charges against your Console project, and request access to user data."

From what I understand so far, user approval is needed again when the application attempts to access google drive without access token(TokenResponse-User file we obtained after user approval). So just by having someone else's client secret without the access token, one shouldn't be able to access the google drive right? I'd really appreciate detailed answers and thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have to you json file containing your client id and client secret.    I could use that in my application to authenticate user's.    the user's will be told that it's your application.   anything I do wrong will then be blamed on you.

I will have access tokens for user that you don't.  Google needs to know who is making these requests.

Comment: Ah it makes sense. And I haven't found any tips on the best practice for storing the client secret.  I'm working on an asp.net webforms application. Could you gimme any suggestions?

Comment: I'm thinking about saving the access token in the database and found your answer to the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623247/authenticating-google-drive-using-tokens-saved-in-the-database . but the link to your sample project is broken and github is saying page not found. Could you please tell me where else I can find your sample project?

Comment: try these https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/a11851d51f13addd70264d01be1928bf I got board one day and made a bunch

Comment: Thank you for being very helpful. And your website http://www.daimto.com/  is a great source for learning things. I have one last question. Now I will store the access token in the database. And could you suggest me a secure or most common way of storing the client secret json file? I'm thinking to just place it in the root directory.

Comment: technically you only need to store the refresh token in the database you can use it any time to get an access token.  If its a web app I would store it outside of http Root if it's a compiled app I would just imbed it.  I have been unable to get any better advice out of Google.